# How do I copy files from a CD-ROM in [Files] using Flags: external?

Tags: external, inno-setup, 16-bit, cd-rom

I'm writing a new installer for an old cd-rom game that has a 16-bit installer, the installer will need to be on the hard disk and be able to copy files from the original disc. I already have a script set up that can install the game if all the game files are packed in the installer, this is fine for personal use but I want to be able to redistribute the installer so others can use it.

I want to have a separate selection box for the CD-ROM source drive like this script: http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Ask_for_a_drive_to_install but instead of it being the destination, I want it to be the source and also be able to select the destination directory. All the files I need are currently listed in the [Files] section, I would like to set them as Flags: external but I have no idea how to copy them from the CD-ROM instead of the inno setup's setup.exe folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can the [{src}](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) constant, which gives you the directory the Setup is located.

> **{src}**
>
> The directory in which the Setup files are located.
>
> For example: If you used {src}\MYPROG.EXE on an entry and the
>   user is installing from "S:\", Setup
>   will translate it to "S:\MYPROG.EXE".

Example:

```
Files: Source: "{src}\readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
```

Comment: No, you misunderstand. I need to copy from a CD-ROM without Setup being on the same disc: "I have no idea how to copy them from the CD-ROM instead of the inno setup's setup.exe folder."

Comment: Why can't you put the setup on the CD-ROM?